# PHP to AS3 converting (array related)

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

i am trying to convert this into AS3

```
$display = array();
$map = array(array(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1 ,0) , array(0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0) ...etc
foreach ($x as $keyX => $valX)
{
    foreach ($y as $keyY => $valY)
    {
            if (isset($map[$valX][$valY]))
            {
                  $display[$keyX][$keyY] = $map[$valX][$valY];
            }
            else
            {
                 $display[$keyX][$keyY] = "20";
            }
       }
}
```

then how would i do this from php to as3

Comment: You're going to have to include more code.  You have nested loops referencing `$x` and `$y` but we have no idea what those are.  Nor do we know what the structure of the class represented by `$this` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how one might end up with such a convoluted set of objects in ActionScript, but the literal translation of the code would be something like:

```
var display:Object = {};

for (var keyX in objX) {

  display[keyX] = {}; // initialize new "row"
  for (var keyY in objY) {

    if (map[objX[keyX]][objY[keyY]] != null) { 

      display[keyX][keyY] = (map[objX[keyX]][objY[keyY]]);

    } else {

      display[keyX][keyY] = "20";

    }
  }
}

/*        LEGEND
   keyX = $keyX; objX = $x
   keyY = $keyY; objY = $y
   display = $display; map = $map
*/
```

Since PHP and AS3 have different behaviors respecting dynamic Objects, one must initialize each "row" as a new Object in AS3, otherwise a runtime error will occur.

The gist of the story is: AS3 does not have PHP's `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)` construct, but the [`for...in`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for..in) is an adequate substitute.